# Is it possible to unlock every character without using Bux?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've gotten every level, both imperial and non-imperial; and I've completed every Vader mission. However, I still don't have all the characters.

How can I unlock all the characters? Is it possible to do so without using Bux?